# Failing in Deploying Web App in Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, tomcat, web, netbeans

Let me tell you what i did..

1. made web app
2. made index.html by right-clicking on web-inf
3. made web.xml by right-clicking on web-inf ( didn't made any changes
   to it )
4. tried to deployed it but failed

i am using `Tomcat 7` and `Netbeans 8.0.2`

Project Structure

[image: Project Structure]

the error

[image: the error]

Comment: Are you getting this error first time means earlier application was deploying?

Comment: No this is my first web application in netbeans

Comment: can you update screenshot of your project structure?

Comment: Index.html you can not place inside WEB-INF . Right Click on Web pages then create index.html . and did you Define Welcome File ?

Comment: you need to your project structure..

Comment: @AnandDwivedi I heard that if we have index.html then it will loaded by default as welcome page..

Comment: @Charlie Okay adding structure

Comment: @AnandDwivedi placed index.html in welcome-file-list and in web pages still not working

Comment: @SalmanSabir . have u seen war file extracted after start the tomcat or not . eg when you deploy war file on your server then on server start up it will extract the war file and create Folder automatic .

Comment: @AnandDwivedi no i haven't seen that file

Comment: I think there is some problem with the compatibility of tomcat with my netbeans cuz my friend followed the same procedure that i followed and he has earlier versions of tomcat and netbeans

Comment: then the problem with your tomcat .

Comment: @AnandDwivedi i installed newer version of tomcat (7.0.67) now when i run the app its not giving authorization, it is asking for username and pass again and again

Comment: you will get UserName and Password Details From tomcat-users.xml File that is there inside Tomcat>>Config Folder Open that file . where you will get details about UserName and Password

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `index.html` inside the `WEB-INF` folder so you need to put `index.html` page outside of `WEB-INF` and *inside the web Pages folder*.

Like this(Netbeans Web application Structure): [image]

You can refer above structure. it will work after that just clean and build your application and run on server.

I hope it will work for you :)

Comment: the Same thing i said on last Comment . Hope this will work

Comment: I made a new project and tried this but unfortunately its not helping

Answer (score -1):

Thankxs a lot everyone the problem was with my TOMCAT i installed the newer version and now it works, I am new to this community and was amazed to see the quick responses from you guys. I really appreciate your dedication of helping the members

Comment: U welcome, and one more thing your mean putting index.html file in WEB-INF and it is working...? I think you are playing blindly., anyway finally your issue resolve

Comment: It was my mistake to make it there